# Compiling DisplayLists takes very much RAM and freezes Windows

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, displaylist

To learn 3D Programming i'm creating a simple Minecraft Clone. I started with VBOs but cause all the data is static i w´switched to DisplayLists.

I have a DisplayList for every side of a cube, only visible faces are rendered. The displayLists are created when the game is started for the whole map of 512 * 512 * 100.

--> DisplayLists created: ~ 3 000 000

When i start the Program my Computer gets slower and then stops updating the screen. I can do nothing except for moving the mouse. I had another Program running with a countdown and even the countdown stopped. Most times i have to turn the power off. One time my Virus Scanner also reported me that javaw.exe took 4 GB of RAM (out of 8 GB).

I make a display List for every side of a block so that i can stop rendering side and blocks that aren't seen.

How can i fix that problem? Should i make my DisplayLists bigger so one for every chunk or one for every block?

Comment: Are you recreating the display lists every frame? If so, do you free the old ones?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your use case, but this sounds like the Flyweight design pattern may be of help.

Comment: What is a DisplayList?

Comment: You want to put as many as possible vertices within *one* list, not 3 000 000 million display lists.

Comment: i am creating the display lists one time at the beginning and it even doesn't finish. http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_displaylist.html

Comment: Isn't it lagging if i have to update a whole chunk if only one block changes? And that way i have to render faces behind me.

Comment: I thought you said everything was static. List contents are compiled *once* and do not change.

Comment: There is no need to switch from VBOs to display lists at all. VBOs are fine for static data (and have the additional benefit that they also allow dynamic data). Display lists are deprecated anyway. And having a single display list per face is insane by any standards. You will have a separate draw call per cube face, which will totally ruin the performance (even if the 3 million dlists would not totally overburden your system). Ypu will need much advanced rendering techniques if you want reasonable performance with that amount of data.

Comment: I would actually suggest you go back to VBOs for static vertex data. Display lists are better suited to storing a sequence of commands necessary to setup some state, not to mention they are deprecated.